# 0|server | TypeError: Cannot read property '6' of undefined

Tags: node.js

Welcome

> It is used as a vulnerability that causes the server to restart

*What is the way to solve this problem?*

The error can be shown and the server restarted by executing this code on the command line

```
SEND_MIC_TIGERHOST_EVENT("new", {
      cmd: 'new',
      it: Number(6)
    });
```

The error that appears is in this line

```
            if (!PeerRoom[UserInfo[socket.id].idroom][ryleeann.data.it]) return;
```

```js
  
  socket.on("SEND_MIC_TIGERHOST_EVENT", function (ryleeann) {
    console.log(ryleeann);
    if (typeof ryleeann == "object") {
      if (typeof ryleeann.data == "object") {        
        if (typeof ryleeann.data.cmd == "string") {
          if(UserInfo[socket.id]){
            if (ryleeann.data.cmd == "new") {
                if (!PeerRoom[UserInfo[socket.id].idroom][ryleeann.data.it]) return;
                if (UserInfo[socket.id].rep >= SiteSetting.maxlikemic) {
                    io.to(UserInfo[socket.id].idroom).emit("SEND_MIC_TIGERHOST_EVENT", {
                    cmd: "new", it: ryleeann.data.it, user:socket.id });
                    socket.emit("SEND_MIC_TIGERHOST_EVENT", { 
                    cmd: "new",
                     it: ryleeann.data.it 
                    });
                    PeerRoom[UserInfo[socket.id].idroom][ryleeann.data.it].id = socket.id;
                    PeerRoom[UserInfo[socket.id].idroom][ryleeann.data.it].ev = true;
                } else {
                  winner({
                    state: "me",
                    topic: "",
                    force: 1,
                    msg: SiteSetting.maxlikemic + " عدد الايكات المطلوبة للمايك",
                    user: ""
                  });
                  return;
                }
          }
```